# How to save an asset image to shared preferences?

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

I'm passing an image from one page to another and I wanted to know how to save this image in the second page to shared preferences.

**Note**: This image is an asset image embedded in the app I don't need to pick it up from gallery,
here's the code for more clarification it's just a draft example from my project :

**Image passed from this page**

```
 class ImagePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ImagePageState createState() => _ImagePageState();
}

class _ImagePageState extends State<ImagePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Image(
          image: AssetImage('images/cake.png'),
        ),
        RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => CandyJar(
                  cakeImage: AssetImage('images/cake.png'),
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
          child: Text(
              'Pass cake image to Candy Jar Page'),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}`
```

**The receiving Page**

```
    class CandyJar extends StatefulWidget {
  CandyJar({
    this.cakeImage,
  });
  final ImageProvider cakeImage;
  @override
  _CandyJarState createState() => _CandyJarState();
}

class _CandyJarState extends State<CandyJar> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
        color: Colors.white30,
      ),
      child: Image(
        image: widget.cakeImage ?? AssetImage('images/mysterybox.png'),
        height: 70.0,
        width: 70.0,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: JSON encode your image and `setString` using Shared Preferences.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Don't save the entire image in  Shared Preferences just save the path of the image.

Comment: I'm trying to just when the image is passed once it will be showing in the other page at all times the Candyjar page is acceded by another page also so I want it to save the data of this image

Comment: How can I use setString or  how to save the path of the image I'm new to flutter so just any information would be helpful

Comment: Could you explain why again? It wasn't super clear.

Comment: I'm sorry yeah I feel I didn't explain it correctly from the beginning I have three pages one of them is the home page , the candyjar page and the image page I manage to pass the image from the imagePage to the candyJar page but the cadyJar page can also be accessed through the homePage but because the image isn't saved it does't show it it only show from the imagePage when I pass the image with the navigator I just want to be able to the save the image some how so it wan change

Comment: So you only want to show `cakeImage` after first going to the `imagePage`?

Comment: Exactly and when passed through it will be saved

Comment: As @AjayKumar said you can store just the path to the image as a string in Shared Preferences. If you don't know how to use Shared preferences you should read up on that yourself and take a look at this: [Shared Preferences example](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences#-example-tab-)

Comment: Thank you very much, I will use this package, much appreciated